# Float elements inside a <header>

Tags: html, css, header

I'm going crazy trying to get that this 2 elements float in the same line inside a `<header>`

```
<header>
    <h1>Hernan esta con vos</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul class="navigation-list">
            <li><a href="#">Nuestra firma</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-ellipsis-vertical"></i></li>
            <li><a href="#">Que podemos hacer por vos</a></li>
            <li><i class="icon-ellipsis-vertical"></i></li>
            <li><a href="#">Comunicate con nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And this is my css

```
header
{
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0em auto;
    padding: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow: auto;
}

header h1
{
    float: left;
}

header nav
{
    float: left;
}

.navigation-list
{
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;  
}

.navigation-list li
{
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    padding: 0em 0.25em;
}
```

Could someone help me to achieve that?

Thank you all very much in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Seem to be working OK, what exactly is the end result you want? Those to be on the same line and vertically aligned?

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/gjVn5/

Comment: The `<h1>` element appears lower than the `<nav>` element. Is there a way to attach an image of my screen so you can see exactly what I'm saying?

Comment: The problem is because your H1 and navigation widths are so long, the navigation is forced to get on the second line. Nothing wrong with your code. Have a look at my fiddle.

Comment: If you want everything to share the same baseline, the easiest is to change all the displays to inline. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/gjVn5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're floating the nav and the h1 to the left. your  elements are inside the NAV.

try

```
 nav {
   float:right
   display:inline-block
   width:75%
   position:relative

   }     

nav ul li {
display:inline;
}
```